# Handling events inside a class (Prototype)

Tags: javascript, event-handling, google-apps-script, prototype, google-docs-api

I am rewriting the question to make it easier to answer (I Hope). I want to have a Button inside a class (prototype) but I want the handler to be in the class also. Works fine if the handler is outside class but cannot find it if within.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
function myWindow(message) {  
  this.SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  this.App = UiApp.createApplication();
  this.App.setTitle(message);
  this.Panel = this.App.createVerticalPanel();
  this.App.add(this.Panel);
  this.Button = this.App.createButton('OK', this.App.createServerHandler('handler'));
};

myWindow.prototype = {
  constructor: myWindow,
  handler: function (e) 
  {
    Browser.msgBox('Click');
  },
  show: function()
  {
    this.Panel.add(this.Button);
    this.SS.show(this.App);
  }
};

function Run() {
  var theWindow = new myWindow('Hello World');
  theWindow.show();
}
```

The error I get when I click the OK Button is "Script function not found handler"

Comment: I am rewriting the question to make it easier to answer (I Hope).

Comment: Wow no one can answer this!, makes me feel better. I am new to JS and GAS so do people not normally use classes with this language as this would be a common scenario if they ever wanted to handle an event from an widget in a class.

Comment: Trying to find a reference but it looks like it is not possible, the reason being createServerHandler is only designed for global functions and nothing else is provided in the UIAPP. I have already worked around it with repeated code but still interested in solving this if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have done a lot of reading and although it is not explicitly stated it seems createServerHandler is only designed for global functions and nothing else is provided in the UIAPP. That means what I have asked for cannot be done.

The solution would have to look like

```
function myWindow(message) {  
  this.SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  this.App = UiApp.createApplication();
  this.App.setTitle(message);
  this.Panel = this.App.createVerticalPanel();
  this.App.add(this.Panel);
  this.Button = this.App.createButton('OK', this.App.createServerHandler('handler'));
}

myWindow.prototype = {
  constructor: myWindow,
  show: function() {
    this.Panel.add(this.Button);
    this.SS.show(this.App);
  }
};

function handler(e) {
  Browser.msgBox('Click');    
  };

function Run() {
  var theWindow = new myWindow('Hello World');
  theWindow.show();
};
```

which is not flash but workable.